Patching Medium section of Blueboard+Plaster? Can I use drywall?
I've got two sections of blueboard & plaster cut out, each 1.5"x18". I now need to cover them back up.
I don't want to buy a whole sheet of blueboard for such a small section, but the local home improvement store doesn't sell smaller pieces. They do sell smaller pieces of drywall.
Moreover, they don't sell small, pre-mixed plaster either. Only buckets of joint compound. This is a small job and I don't want to over-buy.
How do I keep this job small enough that I can fit the materials in the trunk of my car?

Certainly you can patch with drywall. A small qt. bucket of joint compound and small roll of paper joint tape should not be too expensive, even if some goes to waste.
I will assume that you already have (or are willing to also purchase) the other stuff you will need: screws, a couple different size drywall knives, a mud tray, sandpaper...

Yeah, I've got the equipment. I am more worried about matching the finish. There's ~1/8" of veneer plaster currently.

Matching finish is a skill developed through experience. Your question doesn't mention anything about finish; you may want to research previous questions about finish/texture matching techniques. I will say that any patchwork on other than a plain flat/smooth finish will likely be visible (at least to you). Texture matching is usually possible using the same joint compound you would use to initially patch the area.
